# Convert a currency back to a decimal format to continue adding

Tags: currency

```
        //Take value from xTextBoxTotal and store it


        Double Total = Convert.ToDouble(XButtonTotal.Text);


       //Take value from xTextBoxRecieved and store it
        double Recieved = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxRecieved.Text);

       //Take value from xTextBoxTotal and subtract from amout recieved
        double Amount = Total - Recieved;

        //Take the Amount and store it in xTextBoxReturn
        xTextBoxReturn.Text = Amount.ToString("C");
```

The xTexBoxTotal is in a currency format, Same as the XTextBoxReturn.Text.

The error I get when it gets to the xTextBolTotal is :

Double Total = Convert.ToDouble(XButtonTotal.Text); in yellow.

I assume I need to get the command that strips out the $, I thought that the convert.todouble did that.

Any help is apperciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to use a NumberStyles define to allow this, something like

```
Convert.ToDouble(xTextBoxRecieved.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);
```

You may need more than that, this should help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx

Comment: Double Total = double.Parse(xTextBoxTotal.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

`double.Parse(currencyValue, NumberStyles.Currency);`